# My class deletes right after creation in Python shell

Tags: python

I have the following class:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(**kwargs):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        # some serious things happens here
        print("class was deleted")
```

This is how I try to test it in the shell:

```
>>> a = A(param="value1")
>>> a = A(param="value2")
class was deleted
```

Why am I getting message about instance deletion? I just want to test class creating with different parameters. There's some expensive routine coded in `__del__` method and don't want to be performed by mistake.

Comment: The message is incorrect.  It's not the class that's being deleted, but the object instance of the class.  You should have saved the param value you are passing to the initializer, then on deletion you could have printed it out, and you would have seen the first object is deleted because you used the same object reference 'a' in the second call.

Comment: @RufusVS yes, you are right. Message is edited. I just wanted to share my experience with this problem, because it's so simple and obvious, and yet you can spend few hours trying to fix it and googling won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such behavior happens because the `a` variable is being reassigned here. Python deletes its old value from the memory, so the `__del__` method will be called. In order to avoid such behavior you should assign your new creation to the different variable:

```
a1 = ...
a2 = ...
```